# Notification opens wrong activity on KitKat only

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

The following code works properly on Jelly Bean - the notification opens TimerActivity.
However on KitKat, this code opens the MainActivity instead. Is this a bug?

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(ongoingNotificationIcon)
    .setContentTitle(ongoingNotificationContentTitle)
    .setContentText(ongoingNotificationContentText)
    .setTicker(ongoingNotificationTicker)
    .setPriority(99)
    .setOngoing(true)
    ;

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(TimerActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
timerNotification = mBuilder.build();
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, timerNotification);
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks similarly to the issue here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61850

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63236

suggested workaround is to cancel existing pending intent, or use
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: I don't understand any of that. Says a solution is to call `getNotificationPendingIntent().cancel();` but it says getNotificationPendingIntent() is undefined. I also don't know how to set that flag. As you can probably guess, I'm a beginner.

Comment: how to set flag: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html#getPendingIntent%28int,%20int%29, as you see TaskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent accepts PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT as a flag

Comment: I am not sure if this is the exact problem you are experiencing, you get some activity opened anyway. From what I understand, this happens during reinstalls, some pending intents must be cached.

Comment: Says getPendingIntent() is undefined for the type PendingIntent... and the problem is the wrong activity opens. If I call resultPentingIntent().cancel(), then clicking on the notification does nothing, so I don't see how that's a solution.

Comment: @TimSim look carefully at work around at first link. Method getNotificationPendingIntent() is not in API, he define it himself and calling it twice. Once for cancel and once for new PendingIntent. To summarize, it creates two Pending Intents.